# How to authenticate users by an separate API?

Tags: api, asp.net-core-mvc, asp.net-authorization, asp.net-authentication

I have an ASP.NET Core MVC project where users should be authenticated / authorized to gain access to their profiles. There will be a login view.

The users database resides on a separate server.

Can the ASP.NET Core MVC project call a separate API to perform the authentication / authorization instead of letting ASP.NET Core MVC directly access the users database?

How does the API do the authentication and return a result?

I would appreciate your guidance. Maybe a link to an example?

Comment: Yes, it sure can. In fact, this happens quite often in enterprise-grade applications. Concepts like OAuth, JWT, etc. have existed for use in scenarios like this one (among others). Why would an application *not* be able to call a server if it’s configured to do so?

Comment: From [JWT Authentication](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/dotnet/jwt-validation-and-authorization-in-asp-net-core/#jwt-authentication) we can see " No identity or user information is managed by the app directly. Instead, it will get all the user information it needs directly from the JWT token that authenticates a caller."  you can try  JWT token.

Answer (score 0):

> How does the API do the authentication and return a result?

You can google and search  JWT authentication in Asp.net Core application.
It will show how to  create JWT Token.

Besides, these are some good answers you can refer to: [JWT Validation on separate web Api](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64397027/jwt-validation-on-separate-web-api) and [calling the API method using HttpClient](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/answers/questions/1107893/secure-api-with-jwt-token-asp-net-core-webapi)

Comment: Thanks. I'll do that and mark this as an answer if it serves our exact senario.

Comment: Let's assume that the MVC project calls the API and gets back the JWT token, how will the users be authorized to access their profiles next? I mean how will the token be used by MVC views and controllers? is there a standard way?

Comment: @Nina  After getting the JWT token, we should add it to the request header using the Authorization property,  add the `[Authorize]` attribute at the header of the action method. You can have a look at [this](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/answers/questions/551024/the-auth-is-not-working-in-net-core-web-api?childtoview=552561#answer-552561) to now more.

Comment: The example you provided assures that the API itself is protected, since the request to it has the JWT token, but my problem is the MVC project in the first place. How the token is used by it to authorize users, for example to return the appropriate View (e.g. profile) to the signed in user?

Comment: My aim in the first place is to authenticate/authorize users of the MVC project (e.g. logged in users can view their profiles), but to perform the database access and authentication process by a separate API to prevent the MVC project from directly accessing the users database by itself.

Comment: [This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62963415/net-core-3-1-mvc-authorization-authentication-with-token-jwt-obtained-external)  question is exactly what I need. What do you think about the answer posted to it?

Comment: @Nina His answer using session is well. With the help of your descibe , I suggest you have a look at [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65003179/authorization-with-net-core-3-1-with-jwt-token-response-from-api).  Hope it will help.

Comment: I think the final piece missing is: What is the equivalent to using ( Request.User.IsAuthenticated() ) in MVC views, given that the JWT token is used instead of Identity and saved in both the session and the request header?
`context.Request.Headers.Add("Authorization", "Bearer " + token);`